# Azure Mobile Services on ASP.NET MobileServiceClient Google Authentication Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm hitting an error that is weird. It should be MobileServiceClient error when authenticating through social provider. I've this particular problem with Google and only Google.

At first, I'm getting

```
Error: The POST Google login request must contain an id_token in the body of the request.
```

After I change my JObject KeyValuePair from access_token to id_token, I'm getting this error

```
Error: Invalid token format. Expected Envelope.Claims.Signature.
```

This is my code:

```
jO = new JObject();
jO.Add("id_token", accessToken);
user = await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, jO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. Azure Mobile Services API documentation was **outdated**.

The JObject doesn't use namevaluepair of access_token for Google oauth provider, instead it uses id_token. When you retrieve the access_token from the token endpoint, you will need to read the id_token value and then uses it for the Azure Mobile Services Client .LoginAsync() method.

```
JObject jO = new JObject();
jO.Add("id_token", googleToken.id_token);
// googleToken is my own custom class for handling the json response from Google Token endpoint
user = await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, jO);
```